# Catching Exceptions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception

It seems to me that exceptions in Haskell can be caught only immediately after they're thrown and are not propagated as in Java or Python. A short example illustrating this is below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable

data MyException = NoParseException String deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance Exception MyException

-- Prompt consists of two functions:
-- The first converts an output paramter to String being printed to the screen.
-- The second parses user's input.
data Prompt o i = Prompt (o -> String) (String -> i)

-- runPrompt accepts a Prompt and an output parameter. It converts the latter
-- to an output string using the first function passed in Prompt, then runs
-- getline and returns user's input parsed with the second function passed
-- in Prompt.
runPrompt :: Prompt o i -> o -> IO i
runPrompt (Prompt ofun ifun) o = do
        putStr (ofun o)
        hFlush stdout
        liftM ifun getLine

myPrompt = Prompt (const "> ") (\s -> if s == ""
    then throw $ NoParseException s
    else s)

handleEx :: MyException -> IO String
handleEx (NoParseException s) = return ("Illegal string: " ++ s)

main = catch (runPrompt myPrompt ()) handleEx >>= putStrLn
```

After running the program, when you just press [Enter] whithout typing anything, I supposed to see: `Illegal string:` in the output. Instead there appears: `prog: NoParseException ""`. Suppose now that `Prompt` type and `runPrompt` function are defined in common library outside the module and cannot be changed to handle the exception in functions passed to Prompt constructor. How can I handle the exception without changing the `runPrompt`?

I thought about adding the third field to `Prompt` to inject exception-handling function this way, but it seems ugly to me. Is there a better choice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem you're having is because you're throwing your exception in pure code: the type of `throw` is `Exception e => e -> a`.  Exceptions in pure code are *imprecise*, and [do not guarantee ordering with respect to `IO` operations](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html#v%3athrowIO).  So the `catch` doesn't see the pure `throw`.  To fix that, you can use [`evaluate :: a -> IO a`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html#v%3aevaluate), which "can be used to order evaluation with respect to other IO operations" (from the docs).  `evaluate` is like return, but it forces evaluation at the same time.  Thus, you can replace `liftM ifun getLine` with  `evaluate . ifun =<< getline`, which forces `ifun` to have been evaluated during `runPrompt` `IO` action.  (Recall that `liftM f mx = return . f =<< mx`, so this is the same but with more control over evaluation.)  And without changing anything else, you'll get the right answer:

```
*Main> :main
> 
Illegal string:
```

---

Really, though, this isn't where I'd use exceptions.  People don't use exceptions all that much in Haskell code, and particularly not in pure code.  I'd much rather write `Prompt` so that the input function's potential failure would be encoded in the type:

```
data Prompt o i = Prompt (o -> String) (String -> Either MyException i)
```

Then, running the prompt would just return an `Either`:

```
runPrompt :: Prompt o i -> o -> IO (Either MyException i)
runPrompt (Prompt ofun ifun) o = do putStr $ ofun o
                                    hFlush stdout
                                    ifun `liftM` getLine
```

We'd tweak `myPrompt` to use `Left` and `Right` instead of `throw`:

```
myPrompt :: Prompt a String
myPrompt = Prompt (const "> ") $ \s ->
             if null s
               then Left $ NoParseException s
               else Right s
```

And then we use [`either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aeither) to handle the exception.

```
handleEx :: MyException -> IO String
handleEx (NoParseException s) = return $ "Illegal string: " ++ s

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn =<< either handleEx return =<< runPrompt myPrompt ()
```

(Additional, unrelated, note: you'll notice I made some stylistic changes here.  The only one I'd say is truly important is to use [`null s`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3anull), not `s == ""`.)

If you really want the old behavior back at the top level, you can write `runPromptException :: Prompt o i -> o -> IO i` which throws the `Left` case as an exception:

```
runPromptException :: Prompt o i -> o -> IO i
runPromptException p o = either throwIO return =<< runPrompt p o
```

We don't need to use `evaluate` here because we're using `throwIO`, which is for throwing precise exceptions inside `IO` computations.  With this, your old `main` function will work fine.

Comment: Man, I have lecture for the rest of the evening now. Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the type of `myPrompt`, you’ll see that it’s `Prompt o String`, i.e. not in `IO`. For the smallest fix:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable

data MyException = NoParseException String deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance Exception MyException

-- Prompt consists of two functions:
-- The first converts an output paramter to String being printed to the screen.
-- The second parses user's input.
data Prompt o i = Prompt (o -> String) (String -> IO i)

-- runPrompt accepts a Prompt and an output parameter. It converts the latter
-- to an output string using the first function passed in Prompt, then runs
-- getline and returns user's input parsed with the second function passed
-- in Prompt.
runPrompt :: Prompt o i -> o -> IO i
runPrompt (Prompt ofun ifun) o = do
        putStr (ofun o)
        hFlush stdout
        getLine >>= ifun

myPrompt :: Prompt o String
myPrompt = Prompt (const "> ") (\s -> if s == ""
    then throw $ NoParseException s
    else return s)

handleEx :: MyException -> IO String
handleEx (NoParseException s) = return ("Illegal string: " ++ s)

main = catch (runPrompt myPrompt ()) handleEx >>= putStrLn
```

Though it might be more appropriate it to be `Prompt o i e = Prompt (o -> String) (String -> Either i e)`.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. So Exceptions are propagated only as far as subsequent functions in call chain return `IO a`, am I correct? It works now although I desired to keep functions inside Prompt pure. Parsing however is always error-prone, so perhaps it's wise to mark it with IO. Or put Either there to keep purity.
Thank you very much. :)